# Formula to take a parameter and apply to each cell in a column in turn

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a column with values say: 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8. On a row by row basis, I want to apply a single formula in a second column that takes each value from the first column. Something like:

```
= $varFirstCol * 1.5
```

How to use the first column value of each row as a variable?

Comment: You mean... this: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/867-excel-apply-formula-to-entire-column-row.html ?

Comment: "Apply formula to an entire column or row with dragging Fill handle" part of your link helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of an answer.

There is what may be a simpler way to factor values. Put your factor (1.5) in one cell copy it, select the values you want to scale and Paste Special Multiply.

Alternatively, put something like `=A1*B1` in C1 and double-click fill handle or copy down.

Or if `1.5` is a constant in C1, put `=A1*C$1` in B1 and double-click/copy down.